What does a high percentage of dirty blocks mean when using lvmcache in writethrough mode?
Running lvdisplay usually shows "cache dirty blocks" to be 0%. I had to force-shutdown my computer and soon after starting up it was at 99%, and is dropping slowly.
My understanding is that in writethrough mode, writes are only complete after they are written to the backing storage, so there shouldn't be any dirty blocks. What does lvdisplay showing a lot of dirty blocks mean?
